# Find elements that generate the group $\Omega$

Tags: abstract-algebra

Given the set $ \Omega = \{ e^{2k\pi i /(7^m)} : k \in \mathbb{Z} \}$, as $e$ is Euler number and $i^2 = -1$ forms a group under multiplication. The number $\omega \in \Omega$ such that $<\omega > = \Omega$ , in other word, the element $\omega$ generates all of elements in $\Omega$.

Here is my attempt.
I tried to expand what elements of $\Omega$ could have.

$\Omega = \{ \cdots e^{-2 \pi i /(7^m)},e^0, e^{2 \pi i /(7^m)} e^{4 \pi i /(7^m)}, e^{6 \pi i /(7^m)}, .. \} $

I did trial and error but I can't find any element generates $\Omega$ but I'm not sure for what I'm doing. Did I make a mistake? please help me

Comment: The trivial ones are $\omega = e^{\pm 2\pi i/(7^m)}$.

Answer (score 1):

One useful observation is that multiplication by $k$ in the exponent corresponds to repeated addition $k$ times (as $k \in \mathbb{Z}$), and, speaking informally, addition 'upstairs' corresponds to multiplication 'downstairs'. More explicitly, $e^{a + b} = e^{a}e^{b}$ for any $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$. Working through examples with small $k$ if needed, how does this help you decompose arbitrary $e^{2 k \pi i /7^{m}}$ as a power of $e^{2 q \pi i /7^{m}}$ for some fixed $q \in \mathbb{Z}$? It may be useful to note that multiplication 'upstairs' corresponds to exponentiation 'downstairs', i.e. $e^{ab} = (e^{a})^{b}$ - the proof follows fairly directly from the previous fact about exponentials.